# How convert byte to char*

Tags: c++, c, string, arduino-ide

I'm working with a ATmega328p and Arduino System in a Project, I'm trying to get the saved data in 2 spaces of a eeprom memory and concat it. I always ask to google and check examples but this time I give up.

```
byte dataEE = readEEPROM(disk1,space);
```

I normally use strcat, but in this case I cand find the way to convert Byte type to char*

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

My system is working right now with String to solve this. but a I'd like to know a more efficient way, I always read that we must avoid the String.

```
String TimeData =  String(readEEPROM(disk1,space1)) + String(readEEPROM(disk1,space2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
char TimeData[3];
TimeData[0] = (char) readEEPROM(disk1,space1);
TimeData[1] = (char) readEEPROM(disk1,space2);
TimeData[2] = 0;
```

Now you can use `TimeData` wherever you would normally use a null-terminated `char*` string.